# About measuring the percentage of columns

Tags: html, css

Hey I have a simple question about practices which do you use in your daily work. Does anyone of you use of these calculators to create responsiveness ? http://resources.sameerast.com/responsive-web-design-formula-easy-calculator.html .I ask because I don't know whether reset every time the max-width media queries is a good practice? I am committing malpractice?

Comment: Are you talking about responsive or adaptive design? Responsive design almost never uses a max-width on children elements, only on the body/html tag. Adaptive design normally does.

Comment: And which way is the best, that the project was compatible with the graphic design in PSD files ?

Comment: Responsive design tends to be better, but more time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the best practice unless it's used for media queries.

Also, you can use *flexbox* to create responsive modern CSS design. here is a good guide to start with: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Flexbox is supported by most modern browsers, included IE10/11. However on IE it is apparently pretty buggy.

Comment: I use sometimes flexbox, but i read this article [link](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/dont-use-flexbox-for-page-layout/) , and I think that this is not the best choice to use it too much

Comment: Correct, but I think it's OK to use it anyway, see https://bitsofco.de/6-reasons-to-start-using-flexbox/ and, for old IE use conditional comments, in my opinion, even just HTML without CSS with a massage about the old version poor support.

Comment: Another reason from today's news is that Bootstrap 4 has now flexbox by default http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2017/01/06/bootstrap-4-alpha-6/